# Using R for extracing data from colour image

Tags: r, image-processing

I have a scanned map from which i would like to extract the data into form of Long Lat and the corresponding value. Can anyone please tell me about how i can extract the data from the map. Is there any packages in R that would enable me to extract data from the scanned map. Unfortunately, i cannot find the person who made this map.

Thanks you very much for your time and help.
[image: Scanned map showing spatial structure of mineral in Russia]

Comment: So you want to end up with a georeferenced vector map? Or a raster map?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra a raster map would be fine..

Comment: Wait, and all you have is an image of the map? What format, PDF?

Comment: @Swagath the problem I see it, is georeferencing the raster, if you want to do any meaningful spatial based queries on the map. Depending on the format of the map getting the data into R is as easy as `require(raster);r <- raster( "path/to/image/image.tiff" )`

Comment: @joran yes all i have is the image of the map (jpeg). I am not looking for accurate map with with exact values. Even rough estimates will be fine. I am going to try the save the image as a tiff and read it in R.

Comment: It does not matter if it is jpeg or tiff it is not georeferenced then you will not be able to extract data in the spatial domain. You will also need to know what the underlying data actually means. I see contour information that does not seem to correspond to the maps colors. Just scanning a map does not automatically add spatially relevant information. The contours, and other map elements, are also adding information to the raster that does not correspond to data content.

Comment: This does not seem like a good R problem. I would recommend using QGIS to convert to a more appropriate raster format,  georeference the image, assign relevant values to the raster and then gather values at the spatial locations of interest. This is what a GIS is designed for.

Comment: You haven't made it clear what "extract data" means here. You can probably read it in using raster and mapping raster cells to lat-long coords looks like a bit of polar coordinates (if those lat lines are circles) but then you'll still only be getting the colour of the map, which means you won't be getting the red colours and hence the data values. Tell us more.

Comment: why would someone downvote the question. My question was simple: is it possible to extract the data from the map and since i am a R user, i was wondering if that can be done using R. I wasn't asking anyone to solve it for me; but just give me some hints so that i can solve the problem. It is not fair when one asks a question and somebody else thinks that the question is stupid enough to be downvoted.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't about providing general info or hints. Its should be about concrete solutions to concrete programming questions, such that there is one right answer. Anyway, you still haven't answered some clarifications. Given this map, you want to be able to find the value of that mapped red-brown quantity at any lat-long coordinate? Yes?

Comment: @Spacedman yes. I want to be able to find the value of the colour at any lat long coordinate.

Comment: Do you mean "the value of the quantity represented by the colour of the red-brown shades"? Because that is hard on several levels, because of all the lines and other marks on the map. You might end up looking at a pixel that is a longitude line.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). I doubt you'll find anything for R, since R is primarily a statistical programming language.

You're better off with something like opencv

Once you find the appropriate OCR package, you will need to identify the x and y positions of your characters which you can then use to classify them as being on the x or y axis of your map.

This is not trivial, but good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Read in the image file using the raster package
2. Use the locator() function to click on all the lat-long intersection points.
3. Use the locator data plus the lat-long data to create a table of lat-long to raster x-y coordinates
4. Fit a radial (x,y)->(r,theta) transformation to the data. You'll be assuming the projected latitude lines are circular which they seem to be very close to but not exact from some overlaying I tried earlier.
5. To sample from your image at a lat-long point, invert the transformation.

The next hard problem is trying to get from an image sample to the value of the thing being mapped. Maybe take a 5x5 grid of pixels and average, leaving out any gray pixels. Its even harder than that because some of the colours look like they are made from combining pixels of two different colours to make a new shade. Is this the best image you have?

I'm wondering what top-secret information has been blanked out from the top left corner. If it did say what the projection was that would help enormously.

Note you may be able to do a lot of the process online with mapwarper:

http://mapwarper.net

but I'm not sure if it can handle your map's projection.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The blanked out region contains the mineral i am working on. There is no top secret information embedded. I was thinking to scale the coordinates x=0 to 1 and y=0 to 1 and assign a factor to each colour like 0-0.5 is A, 0.5 to 1 is B. Such that i will have a final data frame with corresponding x and y and factor value. I think it would be faster and less time consuming.